# DOMDocument and hr tag losing HTML

Tags: php, domdocument

Using PHP and DOMDocument class to parse HTML from TinyMCE editor. I'm having issues inserting `<hr />` elements into the editor, because DOMDocument keeps losing the rest of the code.

```
# Input: <hr /><p>&nbsp;</p><p>test input</p>

$domDoc = new DOMDocument();
$domDoc->loadHTML($input, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
var_dump($domDoc->saveHTML());

// Result: <hr>
```

I can't find any reason for this, nor an option for `loadHTML()` to prevent this. What exactly happens and can I use `hr` element here?

Comment: it works when you remove the libxml flags though

Comment: Yes, but this adds html wrappers, and body tags and i don't want those.

Comment: @Rcls you can just take those out yourself, just select the body tag children and get those values you want, well its your choice; if you want to keep the flags

Comment: I'll try that. Thanks!

Comment: Well, your solution is a rather lengthy one. I would have to remove the doctype, html and body elements individually while keeping children intact or somehow just jump straight to body children in which case i have to reload the HTML to Domdocument again?

Comment: I just attempted to remove doctype and html and body using removeChild and replaceChild and I still have the same issue. I might think this is not a loadHTML issue but rather saveHTML one.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was as follows:

```
substr($domDoc->saveHTML($domDoc->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0)), 6, -7)
```

The issue was located in saveHTML to which I gave the `body` node and parsed out the tags. Now I get the full HTML out. This is also a one line solution.

Comment: This solution resulted in another issue: encoding. For some reason all scandinavian letters turn to garbage after I insert the node to saveHTML() as a parameter. This most likely has something to do with the doctype that is being created because if I restore the options with loadHTML(), the issue goes away. I do need to use mb_convert_encoding() against HTML-ENTITITES to fix them to ISO-8859-1 but I've given up. We won't be using HR.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that DomDocument has problems when it encounters an HTML string that is not entirely wrapped in a single element. So if you start with:

```
<h1>My Title<h1><p>My text</p>
```

then read it into DomDocument and use the DomDocument object to generate the HTML again, you'll get something like:

```
<h1>My Title<p>My text</p></h1>
```

For my application the solution was to wrap the entire content in a div before sending it to DomDocument. This fixes the issue posted by the OP - if there is a leading hr tag, wrapping the entire html string in a div will preserve it and the rest of the content.